# cubic curve do not have singular point with multiplicity 3

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was trying to prove that an irreducible cubic curve in the complex projective space can not have singular points of multiplicity 3.

---

I try to use the Bezout theorem, let a line passing through this point, it can not have any intersection point, otherwise the whole line contains in the cubic curve, but this curve is irreducible. The intuition is if so, the cubic curve will contains only this point. Which is not possible. I think my idea is correct, but don't know how to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Let $C$ be our curve and $P$ be the singular point of multiplicity three. Consider the set of lines $\{L_i\}$ through $P$: the union of all of these lines is the whole space, $\bigcup_i L_i=\Bbb P^2$, but $$C=C\cap\Bbb P^2=C\cap(\bigcup_i L_i)=\bigcup_i (C\cap L_i)=\bigcup_i P = P.$$ So $C$ is just a point and not a curve, contradiction. (To generalize to $\Bbb P^n$ instead of $\Bbb P^2$, replace the lines $L_i$ by linear hyperplanes throught $P$.)

Comment: Thank you @KReiser, that's cool, why the union of the line is the whole $\Bbb{P}^2$? In the plane it's clear, why it's true in $\Bbb{P}^2$?

Comment: That comment looks a little off - you say you understand it for the projective plane (that is, $\Bbb P^2$) and then ask about $\Bbb P^2$. If you mean to ask about $\Bbb P^n$, you can pick a hyperplane containing any two points by linear algebra.

Comment: Oh, the plane I mean is $\Bbb{C}^n$ , I want to show the case $\Bbb{P}^2$

Comment: Linear algebra will do it for you as indicated in my previous comment.

Comment: got it, thank you

Comment: @KReiser great answer but I don't understand: If you take all lines $L$ through $P$ you cover $\mathbf{A}^2$ but not $\mathbf{P}^2$. The points at infinity are precisely the ones where parallel lines meet, but non of these lines are parallel. So your proof works only on an affine patch ?

Comment: @Sisi What are you talking about? Given any two points in $\Bbb P^2$, there is a unique line containing them. For instance, if $[a:b:c]$ and $[d:e:f]$ are two points in $\Bbb P^2$, the line determined by the vanishing of $(bf-ce)X+(cd-af)Y+(ae-bd)Z$ goes through both points.

Comment: alright I guess I was confused!